# DataFrame with correlation between several columns based on grouping column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, crosstab

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
|file_id|metric_a|metric_b|metric_c|
|'1.xml'| 1      | 0.5    | 50     |
|'1.xml'| 1.5    | 0.55   | 65     | 
|'2.xml'| 2      | 0.7    | 75     |
|'2.xml'| 2.5    | 0.75   | 80     |
```

As result I would like to get this table of correlations between 'metric_c' and each other column:

```
|file_id|correlation_a_c|correlation_b_c|
|'1.xml'| 0.7           |  0.8          |
|'2.xml'| 0.75          |  0.85         |
```

I do it with the following code but it looks more than terrible:

```
metric_a_vs_metric_c_df = source_df.groupby('file_id')[
                                  ['metric_a', 'metric_c']].corr(method='spearman').iloc[0::2,-1].reset_index().rename(
    columns={'metric_a': 'correlation_a_c'}
)
metric_b_vs_metric_c_df = source_df.groupby('file_id')[
                                 ['metric_b', 'metric_c']].corr(method='spearman').iloc[0::2,-1].reset_index().rename(
    columns={'metric_b': 'correlation_b_c'}
)
joined_df = metric_a_vs_metric_c_df.set_index('file_id').join(metric_b_vs_metric_c_df.set_index('file_id'), lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
print(joined_df)
```

Does it exist the way to do it more readable?

Comment: Could you please add some sample data?

Comment: And also, what's the expected output?

Comment: In your input, you have a single entry for each file-id. Why do you need the groupby? Also, correlation is typically calculated between two series of numbers - not between single elements (AFAIK).

Comment: Just a practical tip, to avoid your variable names being half a mile long: the thing you're trying to compute is a ***crosstab***, or `xt` for short. So a good choice of name would be `xt_ac` and `xt_bc`. Or `corrxt_ac, corrxt_bc` to abbreviate *"correlation crosstab"*. This will help keep your lines below 72-80 chars linelength and readable. We don't need to keep saying `metric_...` everywhere. (Personally I would have renamed the three variable columns in the first dataframe to just `a, b,c`)

Comment: @Roy2012 yes, you are right, I have rows with the same file_id and different metrics that's why I group by in me sample of code by file id and find correlation after group by,

Comment: Do you mind sharing a sample of the source data?

Comment: @smci my primary language is java) I do it as research) thanks for advice! It's quite difficult to follow language conventions when you mostly use other language every day

Comment: @Roy2012 I can do that but real data is long non readable floats. I added for readability duplicates of rows with the same file_id. But if exact numbers make sense I could add them with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. Since the sample data is naive, so are the results - but it would work with real data as well.

```
df = df.groupby("file_id").corr().reset_index().melt(id_vars = ["file_id", "level_1"])
ac = df[(df.level_1 == "metric_a") & (df.variable == "metric_c")]
bc = df[(df.level_1 == "metric_b") & (df.variable == "metric_c")]
df = pd.concat([ac, bc])
df["metrics"] = df.level_1 + "_" + df.variable

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="file_id", columns="metrics")
df.columns = [c[1] for c in df.columns]
```

The result is:

```
         metric_a_metric_c  metric_b_metric_c
file_id                                      
'1.xml'                1.0                1.0
'2.xml'                1.0                1.0
```

Comment: I checked the `crosstab`. It looks like it works pairwise. You better understand the problem and asked relevant questions. I will wait some time but I think your answer is a single one that actually close to expected behaviour

Comment: It would be more comfortable to get the df not a pivot table. I'm working on it: ` res = (pd.pivot_table(df, index="file_id", columns="metrics"))
    flattened = pd.DataFrame(res.to_records())
    flattened.columns = [hdr.replace("('value', ", "").replace(")", "") for hdr in flattened.columns]`

Comment: Just for me to understand - instead of a pivot table with columns which are multi-index, you'd like to get a simple dataframe as the end result? If that's what you're looking for, I added a couple of lines to the solution to do that.

Comment: in your approach for pivot to df 'fle_id' isn't countered as column. The code that I added to comment actually do what I plan

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crosstab` it returns a DataFrame, and then apply `correlation` on it.

```
metric_a_vs_metric_c_df = pd.crosstab(df['metric_a'],df['metric_c'])
```

Comment: have a look :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute a [***crosstab***](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) of the (Spearman) correlation respectively between columns 'a'-'c', 'b'-'c'.
This is a one-liner with `crosstab`, which allows you to pass a custom aggregate function. Something like:

```
df[['a']].apply(lambda s: df['c'].corr('spearman',s.values), axis=1)

# (this is nearly working, you get the idea)
```

And here's the boilerplate to read in your dataframe from PSV (Pipe-Separated Value, i.e. separator is '|'), and replace 'metric_' -> '' in your column names.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """|file_id|metric_a|metric_b|metric_c|
|'1.xml'| 1      | 0.5    | 50     |
|'2.xml'| 2      | 0.7    | 75     |"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), sep='|', index_col=[0], usecols=[1,2,3,4])

df.columns = [s.replace('metric_', '') for s in df.columns]
```

By the way, pandas dataframes also have a `corr` function, which computes all column-wise correlations:

```
>>> df.corr(method='spearman')
     a    b    c
a  1.0  1.0  1.0
b  1.0  1.0  1.0
c  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: I need to calculate correlation based on grouping per field_id. I can't use just `corr` on dataframe. I added sample of the data with duplicates file_name and different metrics values.

Comment: That's what the command at top `df[['a']].apply(lambda s: df['c'].corr('spearman',s.values), axis=1)` is doing. (I only mentioned the other more general `df.corr()` as a footnote). And you actually don't need the explicit `groupby('field_id')`, AFAIK